# Preprocessing before CNN: Resizing vs Cropping

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning

I'm using a simple neural network (similar to AlexNet) to classify images into categories. As a preprocessing stage, input images are resized to 256x256 before being fed into the network.

Lately, I have run into the following problem: Many of the images I deal with are of very high resolution (say, 2000x2000). In this case, doing a "hard resize" results in a severe loss of information. For example, a small 100x100 face, easily recognisable in the original image, would be unrecognisable in the resized version. In such cases, I may prefer taking several crops of the 2000x2000 image and run the classification on each crop.

I'm looking for a method to automatically determine which type of pre-processing is most adequate. Ideally, it would be able to recognize, for example, that a high resolution image of a *single* face should be resized, whereas a high resolution image of a crowd should be *cropped* several times. The basic requirements, on my part:

- As **computationally efficient** as possible. Hence, something like a "sliding window" would be probably be ruled out (it is computationally cheaper to just crop *all* the images).
- Ability to balance between recall and precision

What I considered thus far:

1. "Low-level" (image processing) approach: Implement an algorithm that uses local image information (like gradients) to distinguish between high resolution and low resolution images.
2. "High-level" (semantic) approach: Run the images through a pre-trained network for segmentation of some sort, and use its oputput to determine the appropriate pre-procssing.

I want to try the first option first, but not exactly sure how to go about it. Is there anything I can do in the Fourier domain? Something in OpenCv I can try? Does anyone have any suggestions/thoughts? Other ideas would be very welcome too. Thanks!

Comment: In terms of just determining whether to resize or crop if your program can already detect object you could calculated the number of object (being faces) detected in set ratio threshold between that number & the overall image resolution. If you have a high resolution and low number of detected objects then resize and if high resolution snd high number of objects detected then crop. In terms of resizing & cropping if the images are being detected & outlined with a box you can use the coordinate of the box to crop & or resize. This means that you just would need to use detection algorithm first.